# Javascript issue on Android webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview

Good Day,

I have a webview in Android app which loads a resource that uses html and javascript:

```
WebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
//webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
//webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
//webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
//webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
//webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
});

//webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Index.html");
webView.loadUrl("http://electricity.com.om/newbilltemplate/");
```

The issue is that Javascript code doesn't work at all. The comments show you what I've tried so far. Also I tried local and online resource and the problem still exist.

The index.html page doesn't use Javascript but when a button is clicked it uses some Javascript calculations to display in the next page.

This is a link to the exact website that I have in assets folder:
http://electricity.com.om/newbilltemplate/

Thanks,

Comment: What is the problem you are facing here?

Comment: Sorry, Edited the question. Javascript code doesn't work at all

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
   WebView webView= (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
    webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.loadUrl("http://electricity.com.om/newbilltemplate/");
```

and

```
private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried it for both online and local assets resource and removed all other code but still nothing.

Comment: No. The webview shows all html code and load all images correctly but it doesn't show any content that is computed by javascript methods